# Cannot connect from Sequalize.js, can connect from MySQL client

Tags: mysql, docker, sequelize.js

I've got two docker services, one running a simple node server and the other a mysql (mariadb actually) database server.

All instances of a socket file mentioned anywhere in /etc/mysql/ say

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

This will be important soon.

My node server is running some Sequelize code that is trying to connect to the MySQL server.

Whenever I try and connect via Sequelize, I get:

```
{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}
```

However, if I log into the Node docker container I can successfully connect to MySQL on the other docker container using the mysql CLI client.

I think I understand that the mysql client is using a tcp connection, while Sequelize is using a socket connection. But, when Sequelize is throwing that error, it is showing the *correct* socket path, as far as I know. Here is my Sequelize config:

```
const options = {
  host: "mysql",
  dialect: "mysql",
  dialectOptions: {
    socketPath: "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
  }
};

let sequelize = new Sequelize("ibbr_dev", "devuser", "password", options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL socket file is not available in your Node container, it is only available in the MySQL container as it is a file. Rather than setting up unix socket based connection, you should use a TCP connection (skipping the `dialectOptions`).

Comment: Yes! Thank you . I removed the dialectOptions and things are working again. I'll try and remember this next time I'm moving something from an environment that uses a socket connection to Docker.

Comment: Just a note, unix socket connections are faster than TCP connections.